# Paypal REST API call doesn't save a trasactionID using nodeJS and paypal-rest-sdk npm module

Tags: node.js, paypal, express-checkout, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm using the paypal rest api in nodeJS and the paypal-rest-sdk npm module.

I am using the REST API to create a payment with paypal using express checkout.  I can successfully get a redirect url where the user is redirected to paypal to authorize a transaction.

However, when the user completes the transaction, I can see the transaction show up in my dashboard on paypal's developer website: developer.paypal.com

There is no transactionID which leads me to believe that something is not right.  We cannot see any money in our paypal profile.

Please refer to the 2 screenshots, note that the Transaction ID is N/A:

[image: Paypal Dashboard]

[image: Paypal profile]

We know that this is NOT a credential issue.  We can get successful responses from Paypal.  This example is the first step, getting a redirect url to send users onto paypal's site for authorization:

```
{ id: 'PAY-1RE096301S217202BKM2EBWI',
create_time: '2014-03-27T15:16:41Z',
update_time: '2014-03-27T15:16:42Z',
state: 'created',
intent: 'sale',
payer: 
 { payment_method: 'paypal',
   payer_info: { shipping_address: {} } },
transactions: 
 [ { amount: [Object],
     description: '3073910, ',
     item_list: [Object] } ],
links: 
 [ { href: 'https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-1RE096301S217202BKM2EBWI',
     rel: 'self',
     method: 'GET' },
   { href: 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-8B22891089906944Y',
     rel: 'approval_url',
     method: 'REDIRECT' },
   { href: 'https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-1RE096301S217202BKM2EBWI/execute',
     rel: 'execute',
     method: 'POST' } ] }
```

Thank you in advance for helping, and comment if you've seen this problem before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to authorize the payment, more can be seen on paypal's api.

Comment: Hi, I am using paypal payout by using paypal-rest-sdk . Can you please tell me what the api for authorize the payout .

Comment: @AmarnadhMeda You need to execute the payment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#execute-an-approved-paypal-payment

Comment: I also have some code examples here you can look at. I'm using node/javascript: https://gist.github.com/jsgandalf/bbe607a2fbb26d9cba63

Comment: Thank you for the response . I got the solution on jun 26 .  Do you know a way about to generate reports for payouts api